# Difference between examine and evaluate

Tags: differences

What's the difference between examine and evaluate?

Comment: To 'examine' something doesn't necessitate an end-goal of providing one's opinion on that thing; to 'evaluate' something DOES necessitate giving an opinion of that thing.

Comment: Have you looked them up is a dictionary? If not, please do that first. If you have, please explain what you still don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Examine' means that you have accessed the work but you have not given your views or marked it. 
While on the other hand, 'Evaluate' accessing and marking the work. You give credits and also review about positive and negative points, so that the author may work upon to improve.